# Quantity of binary arrays of length n with k consecutive 1

Tags: javascript, algorithm

```
Input: N = 4, K = 3 
Output: 3 // "111", "1110", "1111"
```

I solved this with this code:

```js
function getQuantity(n, k) {
  const nums = [];
  const re = new RegExp(`^.*[1]{${k}}.*?$`, "m");

  // Convert to decimal
  var maxDecimal = Math.pow(2, n) - 1;

  // For every number between 0->decimal
  for (let i = 0; i <= maxDecimal; i++) {
    if (re.test(i.toString(2))) {
      nums.push(i.toString(2));
    }
  }

  return nums.length;
}
```

But I suppose this is overhead solution. Maybe there is better way to solve this?

Comment: Seems like a case for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is you your question Find number of binary number representation of length N containing K consecutive 1

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava yes! I just need the quantity of these numbers, because of it I suppose my solution is overhead

Comment: you might be able to solve this with permutation, I am on phone right now so i cannot write up a script

Comment: If your code is working, even too slow, it may help if you provide more results, for example k = 3 and n = 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10. This will allow us to validate other methods, without the need to implement your current method. Issue is that I don't know javascript, but I may provide another algorithm anyway. I may not be alone in this case

Comment: @Damien I'm not so good in algoritms. I just thought that there is some way to get the quantity without generating and looping through whole list of binaries(for example for n=10) I got 1024 iterations. So this O(2^N) complexity which is quite bad.

Comment: My concern was not the complexity of your method, but the result ! For example, you mention 3 arrays for (4, 3). And for (10, 3) ? I get 520 with a faster method, but I am not sure it is the correct result

Comment: Here is results:  
N=4, K=3 -> 3 // "111", "1110", "1111"  
N=5, K=4 -> 8 // "111", "1110", "1111", "10111", "11100", "11101", "11110", "11111"  N=5, K=4 -> 3 // "1111", "11110", "11111"

Comment: @Damien yeah! I also get 520 for (10, 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method has a complexity O(2^N). Using a recursive or iterative method gives a O(N) complexity.

The relation is this one: `f(n+1, k) = 2*f(n, k) + 2^{n-k} - f (n-k, k)`

with `f(n, k) = 0` if (n < k) and `f(k, k) = 1`

The last term `2^{n-k} - f (n-1-k)` corresponds to the additional number of new solutions,
when a `1` is added in the (n+1)th position, with one `0` and (k-1) `1` just before. Then there are `n-k` bits that remain to be set, i.e. potentially `2^{n-k}` new solutions. However, the term `- f(n-k, k)` is needed not to count solutions already included in the `f(n, k)` term.